# How can I send line number from Python traceback into vim?

Tags: python, vim, tabs, line-numbers, traceback

I can parse out the paths to the files of a Python traceback, and I can then send those on to Vim using `-p` on the command line, so that they are opened one file per tab. So I end up with a command like, for example

```
vim -p main.py module.py another.py
```

That opens each file in a new tab, but I would like them opened in a new tab, **at the correct line number**. So I have tried variations like

```
vim -p main.py +10 module.py +20 another.py +30
```

But I cannot seem to get Vim to respect the line numbers I send in on command line - it always just takes the last line number and applies it to first tab. So the example left me in `main.py` at line 30. Trying variations like

```
vim -p main.py+10 module.py+20 another.py+30
vim -p main.py\ +10 "module.py +20" another.py@30
```

all just ended up with bad filenames.

Answers at the level of Python, or Bash command line, or within Vim script, or Vim-Python would all be welcome. Or, indeed, entirely different approaches

(The tracebacks could come from anywhere, and are not necessarily controllable by me. The one that started me off today was just a set of lines in a log from a server.)

Comment: Does this help you (in which case this question is a duplicate)?: [Vim: Open multiple files on different lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148397/vim-open-multiples-files-on-different-lines)

Comment: I ended up creating a python script for the original problem (parsing tracebacks into vim), which incorporated the solution suggested [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2148692/500942): https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/src/python/vim_traceback.py

Comment: Similar question on Vi StackExchange (mine): https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/quickfix-support-for-python-tracebacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try vim plugin: [`file_line`](https://github.com/bogado/file-line):

```
vim -p new main.py:10 module.py:20 another.py:30
```

*Known Issue: the first filename should not have a lineno.* (I'm trying to figure out WHY...)